# Can we use many language on Github Action Configuration

Tags: node.js, go, github-actions

I want to create CI on Github Action for QA Automation. But there is multiple language are use to install dependecies. Can i use NodeJS and Golang at the same file?

I read the documentation of Github Action, but there is configuration for each language not both. Any reference or idea i can use?

Answer (score 2):

In short, you write a manifest file (in YAML) and tell GitHub Actions build agent(s) to execute the commands you wanted in an automatic way. See, there is nothing there bind to a single programming language.

You see per language samples/tutorials, simply because that's how new users/developers to get started with a CI/CD system, and it is easy to write up the necessary steps if focusing on the ecosystem of a single programming language.

The underlying GitHub Actions build machines (if managed by GitHub), however, have almost everything pre-installed, so of course you can use Node.js and Golang tools in the same manifest and you don't need any specific reference.

> Open [the image pages](https://github.com/actions/runner-images) and learn what tools are preinstalled if you like.

Try it out by combining multiple manifests into the single one, and you will see how it works out.